# Microsoft Word - Hotkeys for different "paste"s?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I often write documents for a lawyer if it matters and i have to write the same combinations of words multiple times (e.g names of persons, companies). Is there a function in Microsoft Office Word (2010) that could help me inserting those combinations of words by pressing some hotkeys?

Example:

`Alt+1` inserts `Bob Andrew`

`Alt+2` inserts `Another text Inc.`

and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Macro to achieve this.

1. Go to the Developer Tab on your Ribbon
2. Click "Record Macro"
3. Name the macro and click the "Keyboard" icon
4. Select the textbox under "Press new shortcut key" and press your desired hotkeys. <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd> may not work because it should be already assigned to something. You may want to try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd> and so on..
5. Click "Assign"
6. Click "Close"
7. Now type "Bob Andrew" in word
8. Click "Stop Recording"
9. Now test your Macro, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd> or whatever key sequence you assigned in the earlier step.

Answer (score 1):

Adding AutoCorrect entries will accomplish the same thing, but using visible text rather than hotkeys.  See the last section of:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/add-autotext-HA010255209.aspx

Comment: I just want to add here that AutoCorrect, even in Word 2010, is very, very flaky. I defined an entry in AutoCorrect, and it would never work within a table. It also would only sometimes work in the body of the document. Better to use something like AHK.